# Echoing home_url() returns current url in searchform.php

Tags: search, home-url

In `searchform.php` my search form looks like this:

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="<?php _e('Type something and hit enter...', 'wbs'); ?>" name="s" />
     </div>
</form>
```

However, I noticed that the search doesn't work as intended, the `?s=` parameter isn't added to the home URL but rather to the current URL.

So, when I'm on the single post page, instead of `http://example.com/?s=term` I'm getting `http://example.com/post-name/?s=term`. Similar results while searching from archives and pages. Searching like this obviously doesn't work.

What's more, if I completely remove `searchform.php` I'm getting the same results so it looks like `home_url()` just doesn't return the correct URL. I have permalinks set up to Post Name.

Funnily enough, simply running `<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>` in other files (e.g. `footer.php`) always returns `http://example.com/` as expected.

Any ideas why this is happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: You will want to read [this guide about Paths & Uri](http://wpkrauts.com/2015/the-guide-to-wordpress-path-and-urls/) in WordPress. Note: The two answers below are correct.

Comment: What is the _exact_ resulting URL in page source? If it's different from expected then you have something interfering with WP API.

Comment: @kaiser WordPress core uses slash in native search form, it's irrelevant to  the issue.

Comment: @Rarst I know, that's why I wrote that both answers are correct. And I wrote nothing about any _slash_ anywhere. One problem that I actually **see** is that the `action` attribute is plain wrong above and will probably output `1`. One can **not** use `echo home_url()` – this needs to be `get_home_url()` instead to work.

Comment: Wait a second. `home_url()` does **not** echo. My fault. It's the current blogs function…

Answer (score 1):

Just like @cjbj says, use `home_url()` without the slash.

> home_url( $path, $scheme ); - $path (string) (optional) Path relative to the home URL.

instead of `home_url()` you can use `bloginfo('url')` to get the root/home of your wordpress site.

Comment: Curiously enough, `echo get_bloginfo('url')` didn't work either. Exactly the same results as explained in OP. Could it be something about my server configuration?

Comment: @Kamil, yes that probably the case here. Look in you dashboard and go to **Settings** > **General** and see **Wordpress-Address (URL)** or **SiteAddress**, and see if it's `http://example.com/`

Comment: @Refilion, yup, checked there too. Both URLs looks like they should.

Comment: What does `bloginfo('url')` return? @Kamil

Comment: @Kamil `OP` means _original poster_, which would be **you** ;)